# Inserir dados em um array Javascript #NODE ERROR( EMFILE: too many open files, open )

Tags: javascript, node.js, for, arraylist

Eu tenho 3 arrays no meu código, INFO, INFOS E TESTE.

E eu preciso fazer uma `function` que cheque se a posição da minha variável teste é igual à minha variável info e caso seja igual, a variável final fique:
No caso da variável teste no código real, eu possuo 167,082 posições.
No caso da primeira posição do array Final:

> ficaria: 201 -  Oficiais superiores da polícia militar
>
> da segunda: 101 - Oficiais generais das forças armadas.

e assim sucessivamente.

```
var info = ["101", "102", "103", "201"]
var infos = ["Oficiais generais das forças armadas", "Oficiais das forças armadas", "Praças das forças armadas", "Oficiais superiores da polícia militar"]
var teste = ["201", "101", "101", "201", "103", "201", "201"]

   for(i = 0;i < teste.length;i++){
     for(j = 0;j < info.length;j++){
       if(teste[i]==info[j]){
         var final=[]
         final = info[j] + " - " + infos[j]+"\n";
         console.log(final);
         fs.appendFile('resultado.json',final, function (err) {
           if (err) throw err;
         });
       } 
     }
 }
```

O arquivo final sempre da o seguinte erro:

> EMFILE: too many open files, open

E Encerra salvando apenas 8189 objetos.

Comment: Qual é o problema, eu executei o e imprimiu `201 - Oficiais superiores da polícia militar

101 - Oficiais generais das forças armadas

101 - Oficiais generais das forças armadas

201 - Oficiais superiores da polícia militar

103 - Praças das forças armadas

201 - Oficiais superiores da polícia militar

201 - Oficiais superiores da polícia militar`

Comment: O problema é que se eu rodar no console usando node ele sempre trava em menos de 9 mil objetos montados, no array info e infos eu possuo 607 posições. E no array Teste, eu possuo 167 mil objetos e não consigo salvar o resultado real  que seriam 167 mil objetos no array final.

Comment: Entendi. Edite sua pergunta e coloque a tag `Node.js` para que as pessoas que entendam especificamente de Node se interessem pela pergunta. Também coloque a mensagem de erro na pergunta junto dessa explicação do problema que você acabou de me dar, as vezes as pessoas ficam só na pergunta e não chegam a ler os comentários. Eu não posso lhe ajudar pois entendo de JS no browser mas não sei nada sobre o Node. Mas uma coisa me chamou a atenção você faz uma escrita de arquivo dentro do `for` não seria o caso de fazer essa escrita só depois que os dois laços `for` terminarem?

Comment: Vou alterare verificar tanto a sua dica quanto a questão do node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você quer:

```
var info = ["101", "102", "103", "201"];
var infos = ["Oficiais generais das forças armadas", "Oficiais das forças armadas", "Praças das forças armadas", "Oficiais superiores da polícia militar"];
var teste = ["201", "101", "101", "201", "103", "201", "201"];

function result(compare1, compare2, data) {
    var res = [];
    for(var i in compare1) {
       for (var j in compare2) {
          if (typeof compare1[i] !== 'undefined' && typeof compare2[j] !== 'undefined' && typeof data[i] !== 'undefined' && (compare1[i] == compare2[j])) {
              res.push(compare2[j] + " - " + data[i]+"\n");
          }
       }
    }
   return res;
}

 var res = result(teste, info, infos);
 console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ivan, eu testei aqui! não era exatamente oque eu queria, pois o resultado do res estava trocado. Mas me deu um norte e eu ajustei! muito obrigado.

Comment: Entendi, beleza.

Comment: Ivan, como eu faria para manter os dados do vetor teste e somente alterar aqueles que possuem infos? No caso, acrescentando aqueles que tem informações.

Comment: Uma condição já não resolveria, tipo: `if(regra) {  res.push(novo); } else { res.push(mantem); }`?

Comment: entendi, vou testar aqui